# The meaning of %lg in C language

Tags: c

I do not know what "the putout result is %lg" this sentence mean.
I tried to use `%lg` instead of `%lf` in the `printf`,like this:

```c
double a;
scanf("%lf",&a);
.....
printf("%lg",a);
return 0;
```

Comment: First stop: [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintfz).

Comment: I think `%g` and `%lg` means the same thing, if `%lg` is even legal. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string I'm not sure exactly what you're asking though, can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

`%lg` for **printf** either has **undefined behaviour** (C89) or behaves like `%g` (C99).

- **Never** use `%lg` for printing, use `g` conversion specifier without `l` to print a `double`.  `%g` can be used for printing `float`s too, due to default argument promotions.

For `fscanf`, `l` with a floating point format means that the argument is of type *double* instead of *float*. Since all floating point modifiers accept *all the same formats*, it is customary to use `%lf` as it behaves exactly the same as `%lg` in `scanf` family.

- Prefer `%lf` over `%lg` when scanning a double.